# Write to outputStream after HTTPServletResponse is committed

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

Is it possible to write response bytes to OutputStream of HTTPServletResponse even if Response is committed? 
I have a Servlet Filter which forwards request to CXFServlet by calling doFilter. After doFilter I explicitly want to write bytes in OutputStream. Currently I am not getting response when I write to OutputStream after response is committed.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
        ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    final ByteArrayPrintWriter pw = new ByteArrayPrintWriter();
    HttpServletResponse wrappedResp = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(
            response) {
        public PrintWriter getWriter() {
            return pw.getWriter();
        }

        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
            return pw.getStream();
        }
    };
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, wrappedResp);

    byte[] bytes = pw.toByteArray();
    response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();

// Do logging after response is sent to client. 


}
```

Comment: You'll have to show your Filter implementation because committing a response simply means the status code and headers will be written.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I have added my filter implementation.

Comment: So you're saying the client is getting no response? What do your logs say? Can you debug to check that `bytes` actually contains something?

Comment: Yep It does. What I want is client should get response before logging get started. Currently client gets response after logging process is completed.

Comment: Are you sure your network isn't just slow and you see the response after the logging?

Comment: Yeah I have checked several times. I can't see the response. When I do the same thing with dummy response before executing doFilter(), I can see the response. The only difference I found is,response is committed after doFilter().

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible issues:

1) If you receive the content in `byte[] bytes` from `pw` (put a breakpoint on that line) that means the filter and wrapper did their job and that your servlet (or other inner filter) did close the real `response` somehow. Or - try using the `Writer` instead, I guess `ByteArrayPrintWriter` does have a method that returns `char[]` so you can use `response.getWriter()` to write the content.

2) If there is no content in `byte[] bytes` then `ByteArrayPrintWriter` does not collect the content correctly. Note that implementation may (or will) close the response writer, so maybe implementation of `ByteArrayPrintWriter` closes and thats why you don't get any content.

You can also try the following:

```
BufferResponseWrapper wrappedResp = new BufferResponseWrapper(response);
filterChain.doFilter(request, wrappedResp);

// get buffered content
char[] chars = wrapper.getBufferContentAsChars();
// modify it somehow
chars = ArraysUtil.join(chars, "peep!".toCharArray());
// flush
wrapper.writeContentToResponse(chars);
```

from the [Jodd](http://jodd.org) project: [BufferResponseWrapper.java](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/jodd-servlet/src/main/java/jodd/servlet/wrapper/BufferResponseWrapper.java).

**EDIT**

Here is the similar filter that worked for me on Tomcat, using just Java classes:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final ByteArrayPrintWriter pw = new ByteArrayPrintWriter(baos);

    HttpServletResponse wrappedResp = new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse) {
        @Override
        public PrintWriter getWriter() {
            return pw;
        }

        @Override
        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
            return new ServletOutputStream() {
                @Override
                public void write(int b) {
                    baos.write(b);
                }
            };
        }
    };

    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, wrappedResp);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    servletResponse.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
}

public void destroy() {
}

public static class ByteArrayPrintWriter extends PrintWriter {
    public ByteArrayPrintWriter(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }
}
}
```

Please note it is a **quick-and-dirty** implementation, used just for the illustration purposes.